# Recovering funds after I lost my wallet.dat

Tags: wallet-recovery, lost-wallet, recover-private-key

I have received the bitcoin way back in 2013 in Bitcoin Core.
At that time I don't know about the importance of wallet.dat - I have formatted my hard disk and install Bitcoin Core again in 2017 but there it didn't show my Bitcoin in my balance. I have my Bitcoin Key.

How can I get my bitcoin back? Please help me!

Comment: Do you mean you have the private key for the address the funds were sent to?

Comment: Your Bitcoins are gone forever  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your private key, you can add it to your wallet with the command
`bitcoin-cli importprivkey "<YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY>" "" false`

(The false at the end is to cancel rescan at the moment of adding. It could take some time.)

If you do not have the private key associated with the address the coins were sent to back then, they are lost.

Comment: No, I don't have private key. I have public key only.
Is there any way I can get my private key from public key?
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no. If it was possible, anyone could take anyone's bitcoins. Your only option is to try and salvage information from your formatted hard drive using some recovery software.

Comment: Is there any place where I can check my Private Kay?